# how to shorten this conditional statement (checking if number is divisible by all values from 1-10) python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, conditional-formatting

How can I shorted this conditional statement in Python?

```
if x % 1 == 0 and x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0 and x % 4 == 0 and x % 5 == 0 
and x % 6 == 0 and x % 7 == 0 
and x % 8 == 0 and x % 9 == 0 and x % 10 == 0:
```

I have tried:

```
for x in range(some range):
    for y in range(1,11):
        if x % y == 0:
            do something
```

However this just checked if all the numbers in x were evenly divisible by 1, 2, 3 etc separately in each loop. I want it to be checked altogether.

Comment: `x % 1 == 0` is always true though

Comment: `if all(x%n == 0 for n in range(1, 11)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
all(x%n == 0 for n in range(1, 11))
```

Full example:

```
test_numbers = (37, 300, 2520, 5041, 17640)
for x in test_numbers:
    if all(x%n == 0 for n in range(1, 11)):
        print('{} is disible by all integers 1 to 10.'.format(x))
```

Result:

```
2520 is disible by all integers 1 to 10.
17640 is disible by all integers 1 to 10.
```

Note that `all` is efficient because it stops evaluation once a `False` value is encountered.

Comment: Ah I had seen the keyword all and tried it but I had it as all(y). Thank you for teaching me its proper use.

Comment: Choice test_numbers you have there, I see someone else has tried this problem!

Comment: You could use `all` like that if you wished.  `y = [x%n == 0 for n in range(1, 11)]` and then `if all(y):`.  It just makes sense to wrap it all up together.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a `for loop` to check if the condition is **not** satisfied for one of the y. The `else` clause is only executed when no `break` happened during the for loop.

```
for x in range(some range):
    for y in range(1,11):
        if x % y != 0:
            break
    else:
        do_something
```

Edit: Further explanation (as given in the comments)

As soon as for one y `x % y` is different from 0, the inner for loop is left and the next number x is examined. The `else` of the inner for loop is only executed after the whole inner for loop has been run through without any break, so when all y satisfy the condition `x % y == 0`.

Comment: This did not work. Had the same effect as what I had tried (nested for loops). It is checking each division individually rather than meeting the requirement of being divisible by the entire y range.

Comment: Have you taken care about the correct indention of the `else`? Its indention should fit to the `for` and not to the `if`.

Comment: That's what I mean: The else belongs to the for and should be on the same indention level as the for.

Comment: Oh I see what  you mean, I had them in line with the if not the for. Thank you that worked.

Comment: So I can understand better how is this working exactly? It is still checking each y value individually (x % 1 == 0...x % 2 == 0...etc)?

Comment: @vampiire Yes and no. As soon as for one y `x % y` is different from 0, the inner for loop is left and the next number x is examined. The `else` of the inner for loop is only executed after the whole inner for loop has been run through without any break, so when all y satisfy the condition `x % y == 0`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please be so kind and accept my answer as reward.